# What is the mathematical structure called if we replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by non negative integer $\mathbb{N}^n$ in hypercube?

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory

What is the mathematical structure called if we replace $\mathbb{R}^n$ by non negative integer $\mathbb{N}^n$ in hypercube?
I am aware of Boolean hypercube which means each dimension could be $\{0,1\}$. What if we expand $\{0,1\}$ to all non negative integer $\mathbb{N}$?
Is there a special name for this structure?

Comment: Integer lattice?

Comment: $\mathbb Z$ is _all_ of the integers, both positive or negative. The set of non-negative integers is called $\mathbb N$ (or $\mathbb N_0$ if for some reason you want to exclude $0$ from your usual $\mathbb N$).

Comment: @HenningMakholm Oh, you are right, I change it. Thanks for pointing out.

Comment: If you define the operation $+ : \Bbb N^n \times \Bbb N^n \to \Bbb N^n$ to be componentwise addition, you can identify $(\Bbb N^n, +)$ with the *free commutative monoid (on $n$ generators)*. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_monoid#The_free_commutative_monoid .

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly speak about $\mathbb N^n$ if you have a use for it, but I'm not aware that it has a generally recognized fancy *name* of its own, like $\mathbb R^n$ is known as "euclidean space".

In abstract algebra, $\mathbb N^n$ with (elementwise) addition is the *free commutative monoid* with $n$ generators, but I daresay most readers would take longer to absorb that description than they would to recognize $\mathbb N^n$.